# Is there is an OpenAPI specification for the Notion API?

Tags: notion-api

The Notion API reference is obviously generated from an OpenAPI spec. However I can't find anywhere to download the YAML or JSON source doc (which would be useful).

Has anyone found it?

Comment: Since I wanted to create a Python client (amongst other things) it looks someone else has done a lot of the hard work, so this may be moot at the moment

https://github.com/ramnes/notion-sdk-py

Answer (score 3):

The discussion page @FruitVodka linked does not exists, but I managed to get  an functioning OpenAPI YAML from [Notion Postman Collection](https://www.postman.com/notionhq/workspace/notion-s-api-workspace).

1. First I exported it to a Postman JSON using the UI.
2. Then you can use [postman-to-openapi](https://joolfe.github.io/postman-to-openapi/) to convert it to a OpenAPI YAML as addressed [here](https://www.postman.com/postman/workspace/postman-open-technologies-convert-postman-collections-into-openapi/overview).

   ````
   >> npm i postman-to-openapi -g
   >> p2o ./path/to/PostmantoCollection.json -f ./path/to/result.yml```
   ````

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem to be anything so far. You could follow [this discussion](https://github.com/makenotion/notion-sdk-js/discussions/36)  to keep yourself updated.